# How MatMul op works in tensorflow?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I notice MatMul op defined in tensorflow:

the Shape function:

```
Status MatMulShape(shape_inference::InferenceContext* c) {
   ShapeHandle a;
   TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR(c->WithRank(c->input(0), 2, &a));
   ShapeHandle b;
   TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR(c->WithRank(c->input(1), 2, &b));
```

and Compute function in MatMulOp:

```
void Compute(OpKernelContext* ctx) override {
   const Tensor& a = ctx->input(0);
   const Tensor& b = ctx->input(1);

   // Check that the dimensions of the two matrices are valid.
   OP_REQUIRES(ctx, TensorShapeUtils::IsMatrix(a.shape()),
             errors::InvalidArgument("In[0] is not a matrix"));
   OP_REQUIRES(ctx, TensorShapeUtils::IsMatrix(b.shape()),
             errors::InvalidArgument("In[1] is not a matrix"));
```

which means the rank of the input is 2, however the following is OK:

```
a=tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None, None])
b=tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None, None])
c=tf.matmul(a, b)
```

it includes an extra batch dim. I want to know **how it works**.

I defined a ngram op, the input is a 1-rank tensor:

```
TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR(c->WithRank(c->input(0), 1, &sent));
```

but error occurs when applied with batch:

```
a = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None])
c = ngram.ngram(a, vocab_size=5000, bucket_size=100000, word_ngrams=3)
```

why?

Comment: if rank is higher than 2, then batch matmul is used

Comment: Yes, so it means we need to do the batch work additionally. I expected tensorflow would do it automatically.

Comment: what do you mean by do the batch work additionally?

Answer (score 1):

I check the code and found the batch work should be done additionally.
matmul function in python/ops/math_ops.py:

```
def matmul (a, b, ....
    ...
    if (not a_is_sparse and not b_is_sparse) and ((a_shape is None or len(a_shape) > 2) and (b_shape is None or len(b_shape) > 2)):
        ...
        return gen_math_ops._batch_mat_mul(a, b, adj_x=adjoint_a, adj_y=adjoint_b, name=name)
```

_batch_mat_mul function in python/ops/gen_math_ops.py:

```
def _batch_mat_mul(x, y, adj_x=False, adj_y=False, name=None):
    ...
    if _ctx.in_graph_mode():
        _, _, _op = _op_def_lib._apply_op_helper("BatchMatMul", x=x, y=y, adj_x=adj_x, adj_y=adj_y, name=name)
```

Compute in BatchMatMul(tensorflow/core/kernals/batch_matmul_op_impl.h):

```
void Compute(OpKernelContext* ctx) override {
    const Tensor& in0 = ctx->input(0);
    const Tensor& in1 = ctx->input(1);
    OP_REQUIRES(ctx, in0.dims() == in1.dims(),
                errors::InvalidArgument("In[0] and In[1] has different ndims: ",
                                        in0.shape().DebugString(), " vs. ",
                                        in1.shape().DebugString()));
    const int ndims = in0.dims();
    OP_REQUIRES(
        ctx, ndims >= 2,
        errors::InvalidArgument("In[0] and In[1] ndims must be >= 2: ", ndims));
    TensorShape out_shape;
    for (int i = 0; i < ndims - 2; ++i) {
      OP_REQUIRES(ctx, in0.dim_size(i) == in1.dim_size(i),
                  errors::InvalidArgument("In[0].dim(", i, ") and In[1].dim(",
                                          i, ") must be the same: ",
                                          in0.shape().DebugString(), " vs ",
                                          in1.shape().DebugString()));
      out_shape.AddDim(in0.dim_size(i));
    }
    auto n = (ndims == 2) ? 1 : out_shape.num_elements();
    auto d0 = in0.dim_size(ndims - 2);
    auto d1 = in0.dim_size(ndims - 1);
    Tensor in0_reshaped;
    CHECK(in0_reshaped.CopyFrom(in0, TensorShape({n, d0, d1})));
    auto d2 = in1.dim_size(ndims - 2);
    auto d3 = in1.dim_size(ndims - 1);
    Tensor in1_reshaped;
    CHECK(in1_reshaped.CopyFrom(in1, TensorShape({n, d2, d3})));
    if (adj_x_) std::swap(d0, d1);
    if (adj_y_) std::swap(d2, d3);
    OP_REQUIRES(ctx, d1 == d2,
                errors::InvalidArgument(
                    "In[0] mismatch In[1] shape: ", d1, " vs. ", d2, ": ",
                    in0.shape().DebugString(), " ", in1.shape().DebugString(),
                    " ", adj_x_, " ", adj_y_));
    out_shape.AddDim(d0);
    out_shape.AddDim(d3);
    Tensor* out = nullptr;
    OP_REQUIRES_OK(ctx, ctx->allocate_output(0, out_shape, &out));
    if (out->NumElements() == 0) {
      return;
    }
    if (in0.NumElements() == 0 || in1.NumElements() == 0) {
      functor::SetZeroFunctor<Device, Scalar> f;
      f(ctx->eigen_device<Device>(), out->flat<Scalar>());
      return;
    }
    Tensor out_reshaped;
    CHECK(out_reshaped.CopyFrom(*out, TensorShape({n, d0, d3})));
    LaunchBatchMatMul<Device, Scalar>::Launch(ctx, in0_reshaped, in1_reshaped,
                                              adj_x_, adj_y_, &out_reshaped);
  }
```

and finally each matrix multiply is calculated in some "Run" function:

```
static void Run(const Tensor& in_x, const Tensor& in_y, bool adj_x,
                bool adj_y, Tensor* out, int start, int limit) {
  for (int i = start; i < limit; ++i) {
    auto x = ConstTensorSliceToEigenMatrix(in_x, i);
    auto y = ConstTensorSliceToEigenMatrix(in_y, i);
    auto z = TensorSliceToEigenMatrix(out, i);
    // TODO(rmlarsen): Get rid of the special casing here when we have
    // upstreamed improvements for matrix*vector and vector*matrix to
    // Eigen's general matrix product.
    if (!adj_x && x.rows() == 1) {
      Multiply(adj_x, adj_y, x.row(0), y, z);
    } else if (adj_x && x.cols() == 1) {
      Multiply(adj_x, adj_y, x.col(0), y, z);
    } else if (!adj_y && y.cols() == 1) {
      Multiply(adj_x, adj_y, x, y.col(0), z);
    } else if (adj_y && y.rows() == 1) {
      Multiply(adj_x, adj_y, x, y.row(0), z);
    } else {
      Multiply(adj_x, adj_y, x, y, z);
    }
  }
}
```