# Implement Tensor Multiplication using C, in correspondence to "mat_mul" operation of TensorFlow

Tags: c, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication, tensorflow2.0

I want to implement the mat_mul operation of TensorFlow in C programming. I was thinking to generalize the tensor multiplication of rank 2 to any rank number.

I implemented the tensor multiplication of rank 2 using the C programming language.

If I try to expand my current solution to support larger rank number then more loops are needed to cover the more dimensions. As a result, this solution is neither dynamic nor feasible.

Here is the human readable representation of two tensors.

```
int a[2][3] = {{1, 2, 3},{4, 5, 6}};
int b[3][2] = {{7, 8},{9, 10},{11, 12}};
The tensor values are given to the program with the form of vectors a_1 and b_1 and their shape is known.
int a_1[6] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};     // shape = [2 ,3]
int b_1[6] = {7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};  // shape = [3, 2]

a_dim1 = 2; a_dim2 = 3; // rows,columns of tensor a_1
b_dim1 = 3; b_dim2 = 2; // rows,columns of tensor b_1
```

The result is stored in the vector multiply.

The multiplication could also be done with pointers of pointers instead of using vectors to represent better the rank 2 tensors.

```
int multiply[a_dim1*b_dim2];
int sum=0;
int l = 0;

for(int i=0; i<a_dim1; i++){       //iterates over rows of matrix a
    for(int j=0; j<b_dim2; j++){   // iterates over columns of matrix b
        for(int k=0; k<a_dim2; k++){  //iterates over columns of matrix a
            sum += a_1[k+ a_dim2*i] * b_1[(k * b_dim2) + j];
        }
        multiply[l] = sum;
        printf(" multiply[%d] %d :\n", l, multiply[l]);
        sum=0;
        l++;
}}}
```

I tried to add additional loops for more dimensions and I read the corresponding links bellow:

1) Main site: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/matmul

2) In this link it is not clear to me how the mat mul works in tensorflow althought I read the response of the colleague, I could not find the same code that is depicted in the reply in github.
[How MatMul op works in tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51832918/how-matmul-op-works-in-tensorflow)

3) Do they use batch mat mul for rank greater than 2 in TensorFLow ?https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/ops/batch-mat-mul

4) [How does tensorflow batch_matmul work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34183343/how-does-tensorflow-batch-matmul-work)

5) https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/batch_matmul_op_impl.h

6) I was expecting from this link to understand how the mat mul operates in larger rank numbers
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/matmul_op.cc

7) From math perspective:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63074/is-there-a-3-dimensional-matrix-by-matrix-product

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_contraction
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/matmul_op.h

Comment: What exactly is your question? Also as I can see you are implementing the "naive" matrix multiplication which will work rather slow except small sized matrices.

Comment: How to expand a simple mat_mul operation of rank 2 tensors (as I depict in the code sample) to any rank tensors. I agree the implementation is really naive,  I am open in any suggestion. My broad target is to create any operation of TensorFlow 2 again using C programming.

Comment: I suggest you use a numerical linear algebra library. It can save you considerable amount of time, effort...

Comment: I will run the binaries in SpiNNaker supercomputer and it is not feasible to load the additional library as I am aware.

Comment: Are you able to implement it?